# Schedule trigger option in Azure DevOps mechanism

Tags: azure-devops

I understand that regardless of commit in the VCS , if highlighted option below is selected then build would trigger as per the scheduled event. Am I correct?
What will happen when we don’t select below option? Provided in 2 scenarios with commit & with out commit?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qk5Nk.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find an explanation here: [Running even when there are no code changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/scheduled-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#running-even-when-there-are-no-code-changes)

> By default, your pipeline does not run as scheduled if there have been
> no code changes since the last successful scheduled run. For instance,
> consider that you have scheduled a pipeline to run every night at
> 9:00pm. During the weekdays, you push various changes to your code.
> The pipeline runs as per schedule. During the weekends, you do not
> make any changes to your code. If there have been no code changes
> since the scheduled run on Friday, then the pipeline does not run as
> scheduled during the weekend.
>
> To configure the scheduled pipeline to build only if there has been a
> change since the last build, check Only schedule builds if the source
> or pipeline has changed.

Answer (score 0):

You configured pipeline for scheduled runs. It will run according to your schedule, irrespectively of whether commit happened or not.

You might be interested in commits-based triggers, which are Continuous Integration (CI) triggers and configured [separately](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#ci-triggers)

Here are some examples for CI triggers in pipeline YAML file:

```
# specific path build
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - master
    - releases/*
  paths:
    include:
    - docs
    exclude:
    - docs/README.md
```

Comment: Hi Konurbayev,  I got it but It look contradictory as per below comment from Aleksandar and from respective MS link,  you mean to say when scheduled trigger triggers as per the schedule irrespective of commit , does it meant to say provided we should uncheck the option "Only scheduled builds if the source or pipeline has changed" from scheduled trigger area, am I correct?

Comment: Yes, the check option will schedule only if there was a change since last run. 
If unchecked it should be scheduled irrespectively.